# Symfony - Path /admin accessible in local but 404 in prod environnement

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony4, production-environment

I have added a `sonata admin` to my website.

In local, i can access to the path `/admin` but not when I push it on my prod environnement. I get a **404** when i try to access it :

**Not Found**
*The requested URL /admin was not found on this server.*

I have removed my cache in `var/cache/prod`

In case heres the content of my `sonata_admin.yaml` which is used :

```
_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_security:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_resetting:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml'
    prefix: /admin/resetting
```

Do I have to configure something, to access these paths on my server ? Or does this has anything to do with the `.htaccess` file.

Any clue of what might be causing this problem ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

**UPDATE :** Heres what I have when I do `debug:router` command on my localhost (can't do it in production)

```
D:\website>php bin/console debug:router
 ------------------------------------------ ---------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------------------------
  Name                                       Method     Scheme   Host   Path
 ------------------------------------------ ---------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------------------------
  homepage                                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /
  _twig_error_test                           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  _wdt                                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home                             ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search                           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_phpinfo                          ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler_open_file                        ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open
  _profiler                                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router                           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception                        ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css                    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
  webhook_index                              ANY        ANY      ANY    /mailchimp/webhook/endpoint
  admin_app_event_list                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/event/list
  admin_app_event_create                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/event/create
  admin_app_event_batch                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/event/batch
  admin_app_event_edit                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/event/{id}/edit
  admin_app_event_delete                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/event/{id}/delete
  admin_app_event_show                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/event/{id}/show
  admin_app_event_export                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/event/export
  admin_sonata_user_user_list                ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/user/list
  admin_sonata_user_user_create              ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/user/create
  admin_sonata_user_user_batch               ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/user/batch
  admin_sonata_user_user_edit                ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/user/{id}/edit
  admin_sonata_user_user_delete              ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/user/{id}/delete
  admin_sonata_user_user_show                ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/user/{id}/show
  admin_sonata_user_user_export              ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/user/export
  admin_sonata_user_group_list               ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/group/list
  admin_sonata_user_group_create             ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/group/create
  admin_sonata_user_group_batch              ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/group/batch
  admin_sonata_user_group_edit               ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/group/{id}/edit
  admin_sonata_user_group_delete             ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/group/{id}/delete
  admin_sonata_user_group_show               ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/group/{id}/show
  admin_sonata_user_group_export             ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/sonata/user/group/export
  sonata_admin_redirect                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/
  sonata_admin_dashboard                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/dashboard
  sonata_admin_retrieve_form_element         ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/core/get-form-field-element
  sonata_admin_append_form_element           ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/core/append-form-field-element
  sonata_admin_short_object_information      ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/core/get-short-object-description.{_format}
  sonata_admin_set_object_field_value        ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/core/set-object-field-value
  sonata_admin_search                        ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/search
  sonata_admin_retrieve_autocomplete_items   ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/core/get-autocomplete-items
  sonata_user_admin_security_login           ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/login
  sonata_user_admin_security_check           POST       ANY      ANY    /admin/login_check
  sonata_user_admin_security_logout          ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/logout
  sonata_user_admin_resetting_request        GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/resetting/request
  sonata_user_admin_resetting_send_email     POST       ANY      ANY    /admin/resetting/send-email
  sonata_user_admin_resetting_check_email    GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/resetting/check-email
  sonata_user_admin_resetting_reset          GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /admin/resetting/reset/{token}
 ------------------------------------------ ---------- -------- ------ ----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Could it be a trailing slash issue? Have you tried the path `/admin/` (with the forward slash)?

Comment: What Symfony version are you using? If you use `Symfony 4.x` check if you added those routes to `config/routes.yaml` or `config/packages/prod/routes.yaml`.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber No i have the same problem with the forward slash

Comment: @GasKa Yes, I am using Symfony 4.1.7 ok that may be the thing, i'll look around it. Thank you

Comment: @Gaska I have passed the content of my `config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml`in my `config/routes.yaml` and just after in a new file `config/packages/prod/routes.yaml`, but I still have the same problem. I access /admin in local, but not on my server (cleared my cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found the solution :**

In **Symfony 4.x**, we need to specify a specific rewrite rule.

I followed the [Symfony 4 documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#adding-rewrite-rules).
I just needed to do this command to fix it :

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

You can also just add this code in a `.htaccess` file in the `public` sub-directory of your Symfony project :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

And voilà ! `/admin` and all subpaths are now accessible on the server.